# Program that computes final averages for a set of grades

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I am struggeling with a little homework task. The point of the task is to create a program that will work out the final averages for a given set of grades.

> The format of a grade line is:
>
> N grades1, grades2, …………., grades5
>
> Where N is total number of students and grades is the ith score. All
>   scores must be between 0 and 100.
>
> The program reads the grades from the user, calculate and display the
>   average.

I am at the stage of trying to logically lay it out on paper, but I am stuck.

I am not asking for an answer but just merely a point in the right direction, since I am new to c#.

Comment: Again, I stress that I am not asking for the answer. Just point me to maybe tutorials or a website that might help me in understanding and breaking this question down.

Comment: Don't ask for tutorials as that's not really what this site is about and off topic. lookup up `linq`, `list<T>`, `sum`, `count`, `foreach` loops. you are bound to find something that will help

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Is it an issue with writing the program in C# (like, what classes to use, what structure to give to the program etc?) or with the algorithm itself (how to compute the average, etc)?

Comment: The problem comes in with the logical lay out, like pseudocode. Which is something I struggle with a lot. @TheGeneral I apologise, and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Coding is a lot like lego, start breaking your program down into small problems, then make classes to hold your data and concerns.

Comment: @TheGeneral I was good with lego when I was a kid, but now that talent seems to have gone out the window. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

riorio's answer is fine, I just want to add pointers to some relevant documentation that might be useful for you for the C#/.NET part. Feel free to keep this information hidden and use it only as a last resort, if you prefer:

- [The Console class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx) for reading/displaying data from/to the user. Look at the `ReadLine` and `WriteLine` methods. (I'm assuming you are developing a console application).
- [The int.TryParse method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) for parsing/validating the input.
- C#'s [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) and [while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) for the data collection loop.
- You might want to use [a List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the collected grades.
- And finally, [LINQ's Sum method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) might be useful for you to calculate the average.
- You might need to take care with this too: [Number casting and type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

Comment: As far as I understand, I would need to use a multidimensional array to do this instead of a list. I need to store, for example, student 1 and their 5 grades as well as the average.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

- Read `N` from the input line.    --> think how you can break the input line
- Do a loop for `N` times.
- Validate each input. --> think what validation do you need and how you can do them
- Calculate the average.
- Display the average.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @SirDogManThing, you are welcome. I will appreciate if you thumb up my answer and select it.